# How to import from local python packages in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

My project structure is something like this:

```
- my_pkg
    setup.py
    README.md
    - my_pkg
        __init__.py
        __main__.py
         - src
             app.py
             part.py
             __init__.py
         - tests
             test_app.py
             test_parts.py
             __init__.py
```

In test_app.py I have the following import statement:

```
import my_pkg.src.app as app
```

In my terminal I can run the file using

```
python -m my_pkg.tests.test_app
```

This runs fine without any errors, but when I right click on test_app.py and choose "Run Python File in Terminal" I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_pkg'
```

I have installed my_pkg by running:

```
pip install -e .
```

If I open up a terminal and run python and in python run "import my_pkg.src.app as app" it works fine.

What am I doing wrong. How can I get my imports to work when running my program in visual studio code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find a way to get the debugger to work by changing the launch.json file:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Module: my_pkg",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "my_pkg",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "env" : {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"},
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 5678,
            "host": "localhost",
            "pathMappings": [
                {
                    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                    "remoteRoot": "."
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File (External Terminal)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "env" : {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"},
            "console": "externalTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

The "Python: Module my_pkg" will run my module by running the __ main __.py-file with a -m argument, and the "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)" and "Python: Current File (External Terminal)" runs the current file open, but gives workspaceFolder as PYTHONPATH so my imports don't break.

I have still not found a way to change the configuration so that I can right click on a file and choose "Run Python File in Terminal" without it breaking. But I just run it in the terminal manually until I find a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

Because your running cwd is at your "test.py" file.

You need to add root dir to your system path

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dir(__file__), "from/file/to/root"))
print (sys.path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your directory to 'my_pkg' and run your code as follows

```sh
python -m my_pkg.tests.test_app
```

Check out the -m flag documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m)

Comment: Yes, I am able to run it like this from the terminal. How can I configure VS code to run it automatically like this in debug mode, when running in terminal, and when running automatically detected tests?